# EasyMock expect method to return multiple, different objects in a for Loop

Tags: java, return, easymock

I am using EasyMock to unit test my Java code. In my mocking list, I would like to for every elements when I call a get method, I want to return a different value.

For example:

```
List<SearchResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
        results.add(fControl.createMock(SearchResult.class));
        results.add(fControl.createMock(SearchResult.class));

for (SearchResult result : results) {
    EasyMock.expect(result.getFieldValue(Ref.ID)).andReturn("name:23:1")
}
fControl.replay();
```

the first time, I want it return "name1:23:1",
and for the 2nd element, I want it return "name2:23:2".

I know for the easy mock there is a EasyMock.expect() .andReturn().once(). But it seems does not working on my case.

Could some one help me one this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should be doing it like this.

```
EasyMock.expect(resultEasyMockObject.getFieldValue(Ref.ID)).andReturn("name:23:1").times(1);
EasyMock.expect(resultEasyMockObject.getFieldValue(Ref.ID)).andReturn("name:34:2").times(1);
EasyMock.expect(resultEasyMockObject.getFieldValue(Ref.ID)).andReturn("name:45:3").times(1);
```

whats happening in your for-loop is same method of resultObject is getting mocked with many times and only the last mock is held valid, so you are only receiving last mock value as output when you run your test-class.

by doing it without for-loop what you will achieve is `getFieldValue()` gets mocked and we tell compiler to return answers only 1 time!

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: No, I think this does not solve my problem, because in each loop, "result" is a new object, so even you set the "times" to 1, it will return the same value as last loop.